# Create nested table with 2 different data in 1 row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, html-table

I am working on building a nested table which has same columns, but for rows, I have to insert data for 2 weeks of hours for each day as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

I have created simple data and called it after the 1st week's hours so they align together in 1 row as shown below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Schedule Timings</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <!-- <div class='panel-heading'>Product List</div> -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><b>ID</b></th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Mon</th>
                            <th>Tue</th>
                            <th>Wed</th>
                            <th>Thur</th>
                            <th>Fri</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">
                            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                            <td><b>{{item.type}}</b></td>
                            <td>{{item.monday}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.tuesday}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.wednesday}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.thursday}} </td>
                            <td>{{item.friday}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.total}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

schedule.ts file:

```
    export class Schedule {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public type: string,
        public scheduleID: number,
        public weekNumber: number,
        public monday: string,
        public monday2: string,
        public tuesday: string,
        public tuesday2: string,
        public wednesday: string,
        public wednesday2: string,
        public thursday: string,
        public thursday2: string,
        public friday: string,
        public friday2: string,
        public total: number,
        public total2: number

     ) {
    }
    }
```

data.ts:

```
    import {Schedule} from './schedule';
    export var scheduleList: Schedule[] = [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "type": "math",
        "scheduleID": 2,
        "weekNumber": 1,
        "monday": "10",
        "monday2": "10",
        "tuesday": "10",
        "tuesday2": "10",
        "wednesday": "10",
        "wednesday2": "10",
        "thursday": "10",
        "thursday2": "10",
        "friday": "10",
        "friday2": "10",
        "total": 40,
        "total2": 40
    },
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "type": "math",
        "scheduleID": 2,
        "weekNumber": 1,
        "monday": "10",
        "monday2": "10",
        "tuesday": "10",
        "tuesday2": "10",
        "wednesday": "10",
        "wednesday2": "10",
        "thursday": "10",
        "thursday2": "10",
        "friday": "10",
        "friday2": "10",
        "total": 40,
        "total2": 40
    },
    {
        "id": 3, 
        "type": "math",
        "scheduleID": 3,
        "weekNumber": 1,
        "monday": "10",
        "monday2": "10",
        "tuesday": "10",
        "tuesday2": "10",
        "wednesday": "10",
        "wednesday2": "10",
        "thursday": "10",
        "thursday2": "10",
        "friday": "10",
        "friday2": "10",
        "total": 40,
        "total2": 40
    },
    {
        "id": 4, 
        "type": "science",
        "scheduleID": 4,
        "weekNumber": 1,
        "monday": "10",
        "monday2": "10",
        "tuesday": "10",
        "tuesday2": "10",
        "wednesday": "10",
        "wednesday2": "10",
        "thursday": "10",
        "thursday2": "10",
        "friday": "10",
        "friday2": "10",
        "total": 40,
        "total2": 40
    },
    ]
```

component.ts file:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Schedule } from './schedule';
    import { scheduleList } from './data';

    @Component({
    selector: 'schedule-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'schedule.component.html'
    })

    export class scheduleComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() { }
    filteredItems: Schedule[];
    items: Schedule[];
    constructor() {
        this.filteredItems = scheduleList;
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
         console.log(scheduleList);
    }
    }
```

So my question is, How should I insert the 2nd week's data below each week 1st data so they align together as shown in the screenshot? `rowspan` would be one option, but it creates the extra space below ID, and Type as well which I don't want.
Any help is appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Better" is in the eye of the beholder and there is no objective criteria in the question indicating how one answer will be judged as correct. That's why these kinds of questions are generally [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That said, using arrays rather than numbered properties is usually a good idea. Also, the `rowspan` attribute of a `td` is exactly what the screenshot appears to call for.

Comment: That's what the question I am asking says, 1st is how to display the data in other way including using rowspan, rowspan repeats data in the 1st 2 column as well which I don't wan't, given I'm using `*ngFor` condition. and 2nd if I can change the data in a better way rather than just combining 2 weeks data together. I don't think this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use arrays for storing the values for each weekday.

```
{
        "id": 1, 
        "type": "math",
        "timeID": 2,
        "weekNumber": 1,
        "monday": ["10", "10"],
        "tuesday": ["10", "10"],
        "wednesday": ["10", "10"],
        "thursday": ["10", "10"],
        "friday": ["10", "10"],
        "total": ["40", "40"],
    }
```

This way even if you need to add third value in future, you don't need to add another property in the model.

For displaying this in the table, you can use `*ngFor` directive, just as you are doing now for rows.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">
    ...

    <td>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let value of item.monday">
         <div>{{value}}</div>
      </ng-container>
    </td>

    ...           
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

You can see it live on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbzzfb

Comment: Thanks for suggesting changes in the json file, Nikhil. I've updated my question and want help in building the nested table.

Comment: @TheUnKnown - I read your edited question. To align them properly we need to make some CSS changes. I'm trying to reproduce this on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbzzfb). Can you also add your `component.ts` to the question? Or at least some values for filteredItems.

Comment: @TheUnKnown - Thanks for adding it. Checkout this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbzzfb). I'm using arrays as described in my answer, and you could see the values displayed as you wanted.

Comment: If you can convert json data to use arrays, then you can use the modified HTML in StackBlitz right away. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I was looking for! One more question, if the data is like monday, monday2, and so on as my original data is, can this still be implemented?

Comment: Yes, instead of using *ngFor, you can use `<td><div>{{ item.monday }}</div><div>{{ item.monday2 }}</div></td>`. But I recommend using arrays.